# How to commit changes to SVN External?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a SVN external setup in my code which pulls all the code for a directory from another repository. When I make a change to that code and try to commit the change, it doesn't show any changes to commit in tortoiseSVN. How do I commit changes made in a externals directory back to the repository the code came from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to commit from within the external directory.

CLI equivalent:

```
svn commit dirname
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was within the external directory but it must be getting late!

Comment: However, files changed in external repository should be visible on list of changed files in TortoiseSVN commit window for main repository.

Comment: @GrzegorzGierlik, for that to work, I think you need to check "Show externals from different repositories" in the commit window.

Comment: There is the commit option ``--include-externals`` in the cli of never versions, but for me it didn't work at least with nested externals